# Как узнать что я больше не отправляю сообщение по UART?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Я отправляю пакет с данными по UART использую для передачи данных RS485 в котором для передачи требуется переключать RTS. Для дальнейших переключений RTS   мне надо точно знать, что пакет отправлен. Комментарием ниже сказали использовать драйвер 8250, но как его нужно подключить, чтобы переключался автоматически?
Это код отправки сообщения:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "unistd.h"

int open_port()
{
    int fd; 
    fd = open("/dev/ttyS4", O_RDWR  | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd == -1)
    {   
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS4 - ");
    }
    else
    {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
        printf("Ok - Port open!\n");
    }
    return (fd);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    fd = open_port();
    int n; /* Количество посланных байт(write) */
    char buf[] = "qwertyuiop\n"; /* Буффер ввода */
    int length; /* Длина строки ввода (Количество байт) */

    length = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(char);
    n = write(fd, buf, length);

    if (n == -1) 
    {
        fputs("Error write!\n", stderr);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Great %d bait(a) \n", n);
    }
    close(fd);

    printf("Ok - Port Close!\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вроде бы никак не проверить что пакет отправлен. Там есть какие то гарантии что если данные попали в буфер то они будут отправлены по UART. Я бы рекомендовал воспользоваться каким нибудь протоколом по типу Modbus. Там в ответ прилетает пакет в котором понятно дошел ли пакет или нет. Прям точно до такта вы не сможете узнать отправлен ли пакет или нет. Прерывания вам тоже не помогут потому что у вас система я думаю не риал тайм и у вас нет информации когда данные из буфера будут отправлены по шине. Можете найти какой нибудь открытый код снифера и посмотреть как там реализован перехват.

Comment: Но иногда даже сниферы показывают не правильно.

Comment: Я думаю что вам не так сильно важна скорость так что я бы мог сказать так: Если данные записаны в буфер то можно считать что они отправлены. Если вы боитесь того что будут конфликты при передаче нового пакета, это мало вероятно.

Comment: Данные я как раз и передаю по протоколу Modbus использую RS485. Но для того чтобы дрыгать pin мне нужно знать что данные ушли иначе пакет оборву

Comment: Дак тогда все просто. Вам же гарантированно приходит пакет, в ответ. Как пришел пакет что все ок дергай что хочешь. Почему вы не пользуютесь готовыми инструментами типа QtModbusRTU или бустом? Это же намного проще.

Comment: Отправили пакет, дождались ответа , посмотрели что все ок. Это по моему понимаю единственная гарантия что пакет отправлен.

Comment: Мне надо работать с промышленным интерфейсом  rs485 это значить ставить канал RTS в 1 когда передаю данные и в 0 когда принимаю данные мне нужно как раз дрыгать rts иначе если я этого не сделаю я просто не получу ответ от Modbus переключать RTS я умею но делается это с помощью задержек (что само по себе не надежно) поэтому и нужно знать ушли данные или нет что бы переключать этот RTS

Comment: Можно поискать, нет ли готового ioctl-а, спрашивающего у драйвера состояние устройства. В конце-концов можно его добавить в сорсы

Comment: Насколько я понял, у вас нечестный rs485, а эмуляция. Эмуляция RS485 поддерживается на уровне драйверов, таких как 8250 в Linux. Драйвер сам управляет сигналом RTS.

Comment: 8250 надо использовать написав модуль для ядра либо можно к нему подключиться?(извиняюсь за тупые вопросы только учусь с этим работать)

Comment: может poll или epoll то что нужно? драйвер шлёт какие-то сигналы?

Comment: Для этого нужно использовать [tcdrain](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcdrain).